# What are these variables inside a docker compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localstack

Given [this docker compose file taken straight out of the localstack documentation](https://docs.localstack.cloud/getting-started/installation/#starting-localstack-with-docker-compose), what are these variables?

[image]

- `${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}`
- `${DEBUG-}`
- `${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}`

Like .. are these setup *outside* of this file, somewhere?

I'm not interested in what they *represent* .. just where the values are set and get replaced/substituted into/from.

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/).

You can set them in many different ways and it depends on the operating system.

Comment: AH! so they are defined outside of the file, in my OS env vars?

Comment: Yes, they can be defined in multiple ways. One typical option is creating a .env file alongside the compose file and defining them there. On Linux you can use `export VAR="value"` or prepend the compose command like `VAR="value" docker compose ...`

Comment: Can you [edit] the answer to include more details than just the link to the Compose documentation?