# Is there a default value for localstack's ${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR} variable if one is not defined?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localstack

In a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76304321/18666425) I asked what some environment variables are inside a LocalStack's docker-compose file; for example, a variable reference `${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}`.

For the variable `${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR}` : if this is not defined in an environment variable, what will happen?

[The docs says this](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/filesystem/#localstack-volume) (but I don't understand / find it ambiguous):

> When using the CLI to start LocalStack, the volume directory can be configured via the LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR. It should point to a directory on the host which is then automatically mounted into /var/lib/localstack. The defaults are:
>
> Mac: ~/Library/Caches/localstack/volume
> Linux: ~/.cache/localstack/volume
> Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%/localstack/cache/volume

- Firstly, I'm not sure if using `docker compose` is considered "CLI to start LocalStack"?
- Secondly, is this suggesting that if this value is not provided *anywhere* (ie. no env var) then it will replace the empty/missing value, with one of those from the list above ☝ based on the host OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}` syntax provides a default: if the `LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR` environment variable is either not set or set to an empty string in the host environment when `docker-compose` runs, then the text `./volume` is used instead.

Compose supports a limited number of [environment variable expansion](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) syntaxes: `${VARIABLE:-default}` provides a default value, and `${VARIABLE:?error}` prints an error if a value is empty or isn't set.  Both syntaxes can be used without the colon `:`, in which case a set-but-empty value is accepted.  This is a subset of the [standard Bourne shell parameter expansion syntaxes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02); the remainder are not supported.

Your original question had a PNG file that looked like it contained this more complete Compose fragment:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack
```

So if `$LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR` is set on the host, that directory is mounted into `/var/lib/localstack`; if nothing is set, then `./volume` is (relative to the current directory, created if necessary).

This specific directory name doesn't match the documentation you quote, but the behavior (that the directory is mounted on to `/var/lib/localstack`) is correct.  There isn't Compose syntax to specify an OS-specific default like what that documentation would imply.

Comment: AH! so the format is like this: `${name_of_env_var:-<default value to use if none found OR the value is string.empty>:<directory inside the docker image>}` ?

Comment: Correct.  That's a combination of generic `${VARIABLE:-default}` environment-variable expansion syntax, placed inside `volumes: [/host/path:/container/path]` bind-mount syntax.